# Is mining with a smartphone possible?

Tags: mining

I would like to know if there is a way to mine with my smartphone and if there is (any other currency) would it be useful to buy a cheap used cell phone (format everything) and let it mine for a long term?

Comment: The amount of money you get from mining a cryptocurrency is proportional to the amount of computational power you waste. What is the point of mining on a weak device?

Answer (score 2):

> I would like to know if there is a way to mine with my smartphone

You can mine Monero using either [XMRig](https://github.com/xmrig/xmrig) or `monerod` on Android phones.

> would it be useful to buy a cheap used cell phone (format everything) and let it mine for a long term?

You'd want an Android phone with 4 GB RAM, and if running the daemon, a big SSD.